# git clone and merge with the latest angular

Tags: angular

I pushed an Angular 7 project to GitHub from machine A and cloned the project to another machine B.  On machine B, I updated the project to Angular 9.  The project compiles and runs fine on machine B.  Then I pushed the update to GitHub.  On machine A, I merged the updated commits, and did a npm install to make sure that the new modules are installed. However, I ran into lots of ng errors, and could not build the project.  Do I have to do the upgrade on each machine?  Thanks.

Comment: Your approach should work if all steps were done correctly. Did you update the angular-cli on machine A as well? It is often installed globally.

Comment: I used ng update @anglular/cli on machine, but it says the local cli is older.  So I use npm install @angluar/cli -g then another npm install in the project folder.  The ng upgrade doesn't work.

Comment: npm also throws lots errors that no such file or directory in node_modules\\.staging\....

Comment: It finally aborted with FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain